# Append ECHO to Text File and Limit to 30 Days

Tags: date, text, batch-file, append, dos

I've spent this morning scouring Google, and having turned up empty-handed have come here to find my answer. And you guys always deliver awesomeness.

At the end of a batch file, I want to append a date/time to a text file. This will serve as a simple history log file. That part is easy.

Code:

```
ECHO %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2% %TIME% Process Complete >> C:\Installs\~AcctRefreshLog.txt
```

Output:

```
20130624 11:51:32.45 Process Complete
```

Now, I want to limit this to 30 days of history. That is what I have come to you to find. I had thought about creating individual files with the date/time in the filename in a folder, and inserting commands to delete any files older than 30 days, but the boss wants a small footprint, a single file to use.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: what about telling your boss, he/she should pay for a [programmer](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) ?

Comment: More details please: Do you want to _delete lines_ with dates older than 30 days from the log file? Have this log file other different information at beginning?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f %%C in  ('find /c /v "" ^<C:\Installs\~AcctRefreshLog.txt') do set count=%%C
if %count% LSS 30 (
   ECHO %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2% %TIME% Process Complete >> C:\Installs\~AcctRefreshLog.txt
)
```

EDIT:

```
for /f %%C in  ('findstr /r /n "[0-9][0-9]**.**[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*\.[0-9]*.*Process Complete " ^<C:\Installs\~AcctRefreshLog.txt ^| find /c "Process Complete"') do set /a count=%%C+1
    if %count% LSS 30 (
       ECHO %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2% %TIME% Process Complete >> C:\Installs\~AcctRefreshLog.txt
    ) else (
     ECHO %DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2% %TIME% Process Complete > C:\Installs\~AcctRefreshLog.tx

)
```

Comment: Aaah.He might print other things there.I should count `XX:XX:XX.XX process complete`.Will fix this

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "skip="
SET "targetdate=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%"
SET /a targetdate=20130624
:: Adjust back 1 month then compensate for was-January
SET /a targetdate-=100
IF %targetdate:~-4,2%==00 SET /a targetdate-=8800
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=: " %%i IN (
  'findstr /n /i "process complete" yourlogfile.txt') DO (
 IF "%%j" lss "%targetdate%" SET skip=skip=%%i
 IF "%%j" geq "%targetdate%" GOTO trunc
)
:trunc
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*%skip%delims=:" %%i IN ('findstr /n "$" yourlogfile.txt') DO ECHO(%%j
)>newlogfile.txt

ECHO MOVE /y newlogfile.txt yourlogfile.txt

GOTO :eof
```

In the absence of further information, I've assumed that the only lines in your logfile that contain the string "process complete" are those you mention; also that you need to preserve empty lines and most importantly that we can adopt a rubbery definition of "30 days".

Since my date format differs from yours, I've simply overriden the date with `20130624`. You'd need to delete that line.

From the current date in format yyyymmdd, subtract 100 giving same-day-last-month. If the resultant month is `00` then current month is January, so subtract a further 8800 (=100000 - 1200)

Next, look for the last log-line number containing the "process complete" string that has a date LESS than the date a month or so ago, and build a `skip` subclause to skip up to that line number (which is to be removed, since these are more than a month old)

Then apply the SKIP calculated to a `findstr /n` to build a new file - minus the unwanted data.

I've left the MOVE as an `ECHO` so that the before and after versions are available. After checking, remove the `ECHO` to replace the old logfile with the new.

If you want the calculation to be exactly 30 days, then it's simply a matter of playing around a little with the target date.